# How to convert decimal to Variable Byte code & gamma code

Tags: binary, numbers, decimal, gamma

#### How do you convert the decimal number 777 to the equivalent VB & gamma codes?

I've been [reading up](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/gamma-codes-1.html) on gamma codes. I see where they get the unary codes from the decimal but not where the length & offset comes from. I also understand that the gamma code is just the length (of the unary code) concatenated with the offset.

Comment: Well like I said I've gotten from decimal to unary. And length & offset to gamma. But for the life of me I can't seem to see the connection. And I cannot find anything on VB codes anywhere online and nothing but that link on gamma codes. Nothing whatsoever in my notes

Answer (score 8):

777 in binary code is **1100001001**

**Gamma code**

- calculate offset: remove the first 1 is **100001001**
- calculate length: how many bit of offset(9 bits) in unary code **1111111110** (nine 1s and one 0)
- put them together **1111111110100001001**

---

**VB code**

- Get the last seven bits from the binary code **1100001001** is **0001001**, add 1 as the "head" bit (**0001001** -> **10001001**) because there are still 3 bits left in the original binary code.
- Get the remain 3 bits, this time use 0 as the "head" bit (**110** -> **00000110**) because there is no remainder in the original binary code
- put these two bytes together **0000011010001001** is the VB code.

In esence, VB code splits the gap (in binary) into 7 bit partitions and set the continuation bit/1st bit of last/right most 7 bits part to 1 and all other parts's continuation bit to 0.

---

Comment: 'calculate length: how many bit of offset(9 bits) in unary code 1111111110 (nine 1s and one 0)'  --> Can you explain this a little more? I'm lost at this point

Answer (score 1):

#### 777 in binary code: 1100001001

- VB code: `00000110 10001001` (start to fill 7 bytes if you did not finish put `1` on the 8th bit else `0`)
- gamma code: `1111111110100001001`
- offset: `100001001`
- length: `1111111110`

Comment: Could you explain how you did that?